# Unable to run psql command from within a BASH script

Tags: macos, bash, postgresql

I have run into a problem with the psql command in my BASH script as I am trying to login to my local postgres database and submit a query. I am using the command in the following way:

`psql -U postgres -d rebasoft_appauditor -c "SELECT * FROM katan_scripts"`

However, I get the following error message.

> psql: FATAL:  Ident authentication failed for user "postgres"

This runs perfectly fine from the command line after I appended the following changes to /var/lib/pgsql/data/pg_hba.conf:

> local all all trust
>
> host all all 127.0.0.1/32 trust

Also, could this please be verified for correctness?

I find it rather strange that database authentication works fine on the command line but in a script it fails. Could anyone please help with this?

Note: I am using MAC OSX

Answer (score 0):

It might possibly depend on your bash script.

Watch for the asterisk (`*`) not be replaced with the file names in your current directory. And possibly a semicolon or `\g` might help to actually send the SQL statement to the database server.